# Martingale stopping probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Suppose $A_i$ is $1.4$ with 0.3 probability, $1$ with 0.4 probability, and $0.6$ with 0.3 probability. Also, $A_0, A_1, A_2, ...$ are i.i.d random variables.

A Martingale sequence of interest is $X_n$ where $X_0 = 1$ and $X_n = \prod_{=1}^{n} A_i$ for $n>0$. I am considering a stopping time $T$ such that $X_n \geq 2$ for the first time.

I want to derive the probability $P(T=n)$ for each $n=1,2,...$, the sum of those probabilities ($\sum_{i=1}^n P(T=i)$) for each $n=1,2,...$, and the limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n P(T=i)$ as $n$ goes to infinity. I have a simulation result that says the limit is around 0.4. However, I am stuck figuring out the exact likelihood and limit (I tried to apply the optional stopping theorem, but I found that the boundedness assumption does not hold here). How can I derive those probabilities?

Comment: I just edited the question. I want to get the infinite series of those probabilities.

Comment: Note that you can apply the optional stopping theorem, but I don't know how you would find the distribution of $X_T$.  The only thing that's apparent is that $\{T = \infty\} = \{X_T = 0\}$ and $\{T < \infty\} = \{X_T \in (2, 2.8)\}$.  From this, you do immediately find (via optional stopping) that $1/2.8 < P(T < \infty) < 1/2$, but I don't know how you could go further.

Comment: Can I still apply the optional stopping theorem even if $P(X_T = 0) = 0$?

Comment: You have to define $X_\infty$ to be the a.s. limit to use the optional stopping theorem in this case, which in your problem means $X_\infty=0$ on $T=\infty$, which has a positive probability.  A different problem might have $P(X_T=0)=0$, and the optional stopping could apply there, but it's false in your problem, so it's irrelevant.