# Calculating the likelihood of a Martingale reaching a certain value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

Suppose $A_i$ is $1.4$ with 0.3 probability, $1$ with 0.4 probability, and $0.6$ with 0.3 probability. Also, $A_0, A_1, A_2, ...$ are i.i.d random variables.

A Martingale sequence of interest is $X_n$ where $X_0 = 1$ and $X_n = \prod_{=1}^{n} A_i$ for $n>0$. I am considering a stopping time $T$ such that $X_n \geq 2$ for the first time.

I want to derive the probability $P(T=n)$ for each $n=1,2,...$, the sum of those probabilities ($\sum_{i=1}^n P(T=i)$) for each $n=1,2,...$, and the limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n P(T=i)$ as $n$ goes to infinity. I have a simulation result that says the limit is around 0.4. However, I am stuck figuring out the exact likelihoods.

One way I tried is by taking the log of $X_n$. Then, $Y_n = log(X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} log(A_i)$, and $Y_n$ seems like an asymmetric random walk. Is there any theorem to apply to this example to get the probability of $Y_n$ reaching $log(2)$ for the first time at each period $n$? Or is there any other way to calculate the aforementioned probabilities instead of taking the log?

Comment: Is your wish to find $P(T=n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n P(T=i)$ just in order to find the limit?  If so, you can simplify quite a bit by ignoring the first two quantities.  I still don't know a way to find the exact probability due to the fact $X_T$ can be up to $2.8$, which breaks the common method of using the optional stopping theorem to find the exact value, but you can still iterate it to find better and better approximations.  This is the method I was referencing [the last time you asked this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4853053/694754).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am more interested in finding $P(T=n)$ itself. By the way, can your method be a proof that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(T=i)$ converges to $p<1$?

Comment: The fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n P(T=i)$ converges to $p \leq 1$ is just from the $\sigma$-additivity and monotonicity of $P$.  The method I mentioned is the optional stopping theorem, which proves at once that $1/2.8 < p \leq 1/2$.  Further iterations can shrink this interval, but they become cumbersome if we care about $T$ itself rather than just the event $\{T < \infty\}$, which is all that appears in the limit.